# How to find centroids or geolocate ISO 3166 codes?

Tags: python, geospatial, geopy, iso-3166

Is there a way to geolocate ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 codes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) and get the centroid of the item ?

I would like to place a marker (a disk proportionnal to a quantity) for different countries indicated by the ISO 3166.

I work with python and have tested geopy.geocoders but without success.

Any help welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the geographic center of countries. This type of data is commonly avaliable and [here](https://gavinr.com/open-data/world-countries-centroids/) is one such place you can download it.

Here is a [second resource](https://github.com/komsitr/country-centroid) which does include both Hong Kong snd Taiwan.

Comment: Yes, I had a look before posting. There is no Taiwan and Hong Kong.

Comment: So do you just need the geographic centers for Taiwan and Hong Kong then?

Comment: Included data for Hong Kong and Taiwan.

Comment: Yes, as well as the geographic center of Europe.
What do you mean as "Included data" ?

Comment: I think what your looking for covers much more than a single question. Maybe take stock of what you have and what you need then maybe post a new and much more detailed and focused question.

Comment: Sorry, the second resource is perfect. Thanks.
Just missing geographical center of the Europe (27 nations).